# Two arduino unit communication

Tags: arduino, rf, communication, infrared

OK plain and simple I'm not sure to use IR or RF. This is short distance up to maybe 10 ft.

I have an Arduino Uno that I have all set up here. I press a button and it carries out its code. This is working all fine and dandy.

Now I want to expand a little. I want a second Uno to remotely start up when the first one does. So the first Uno just needs send a signal to simply initiate the second one's loop. Maybe eventually work in reverse as well. Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions, or shortcuts?

Comment: Why does it need to be wireless? How reliable must it be? How quick must the communication be? Is line of sight reliable enough? IR is pretty cheap and simple, and there is Arduino code on the web. OTOH RF sounds sexier :-) I realise that this is starting simple, However, does it require two-way communication, so that both Arduino's 'know' that the other has got the message, or is it enough for each one to tell the other to do something with a 'fire and forget' message? How much time and money might a good solution cost? (I.e. time, up to 5 days is cheap, and I have $10 to spend, or whatever)

Comment: Line of sight is fine this is basically a toy teleporter, and its just enough for each to tell the other to do something. as for money I buy as I need but I have RF modules (433Mhz RF Transmitter Module and Receiver Link Kit for Arduino ARM MCU WL) and I probably have IR components from one radioshack kit or another. time, this is an on-going hobby thing so theres no deadline. I apologize for my vagueness.

Comment: It is your first post, so I don't worry too much about vagueness, *yet* :-) I like to know whether something is hobby/ learning/experiments vs work/product so that I can pitch my answers at a reasonable level.

Answer (score 1):

For non-critical, "fire and forget" messages, both IR and wireless will work. Both are pretty cheap.

I would probably want to do IR RC for a 'toy' because it also might be fun to use an existing, or low-cost IR remote control too.

That way you could also build a 'User Interface' to the toy which looks quite professional, is very cheap (£1) if that became interesting. Imagine, you could even trigger the toy using your TV remote or something. (IR remotes are one of the cheapest, and most flexible ways to make a reasonable looking user interface to small projects)

IR can be done for about £1 for each end of a one way communication.

If you want to learn about it, it'd further justify using IR. It is pretty interesting, and is relatively easy to understand, so that you could even make it from raw components if that became interesting. It works reliably for, probably, billions of consumer products.

IR generates very little "communication pollution". It is extremely unlikely that an IR system would have any impact on a neighbour. Wireless isn't quite as well behaved. Clumsily implemented wireless communication in the same vicinity could interfere with one another.

There are web sites offering complete Arduino code, and advice on how to build and test IR remote control. For example [IR and "Ken Shirriff](http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html)